# Who use the fabric-ca-client?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Who uses the fabric-ca-client?
Does the user use the fabric-ca-client or ca's admin  use the fabric-ca-client?
And Is the fabric-ca-server the ca itself?
I want to know the relationship between fabric-ca-client and fabric-ca-server.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fabric CA-Server can be used to host one or multiple Certificate-authorities(CA) for your fabric networks. Whereas, Fabric CA-client consists of some REST calls which can be used to register identities, issuance of certificates, certification revocation, etc. Moreover, these all can be done by any external Certificate authorities and by OpenSSL too.